# entering to database through sqlplus from putty

Tags: sqlplus

i have logged in to Putty. I need to connect to sqlplus to issue SQL commands. but when I type sqlplus it is throwing an error 'sqlplus  not found'. what should I do? can somebody tell me how will I enter to sqlplus through putty?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to login as a "normal user", run the command ". oraenv" from command line:

```
[oracle@dba-db1 ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [] ? dbadb
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /x01
```

It will prompt for the Oracle SID (which you now from the person you tells you the information to connect to it. This script will then automatically set the corrent environment variables for you.

Login to the database with

```
sqlplus <username>/<password>
```

Comment: when i issue .oraenv it is not recognizing and showing bash error

Comment: by the way..the DB is installed in AIX server

Comment: Watch the blank space between . and oraenv!

Comment: yeah i issued the comment like that only..i ,mean '. oraenv'